# Diagnosing stuck temperature gauge on Vauxhall Astra Mk3/F

Tags: vauxhall, opel, gauges, astra

The water temperature gauge on my Mk3 Vauxhall Astra 1.4 (`C14SE` engine) does not move at all when the car is started - it stays at the bottom (indicating less than 70 degrees).

I would like to fix this so that I can see if the car is overheating.

How can I diagnose the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is either the sender (most likely), the gauge, or the wiring between them.  Some vehicles have a separate sender for the gauge.  The usual way to test the sender is to measure the resistance when the engine is cold and when the engine is hot.  For 1 pin senders, measure between the output and ground.  For 2 pin sensors, measure between the 2 pins.